# About the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} (\frac{\sin x}x)^{1/{x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

About the limit  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^{1/{x^2}}$

Finding it:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\exp\left(\frac{\ln \frac{\sin x}{x}}{x^2}\right)=\lim_{x\to \infty}\exp\left(\frac{\ln 1}{x^2}\right)=\exp(0)=1$$

But when I place various numbers in $\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^{1/{x^2}}$ I get many times results in complex numbers so I'm starting to doubt if my calculation is correct. Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: Please refrain from using `\left` and `\right` in titles because it causes issues with the HTML preview being much too tall.

Comment: We have $$\lim_{x\nearrow (2k+1)\pi} \biggl(\frac{\sin x}{x}\biggr)^{1/x^2} = 0$$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$. On the other hand, for $a_k = (2k+1/2)\pi$, we have $$\biggl(\frac{\sin a_k}{a_k}\biggr)^{1/a_k^2} = \frac{1}{a_k^{1/a_k^2}} \to 1.$$ So the limit you're looking for does not exist.

Comment: So rubik's answer is actually wrong? @DanielFischer

Comment: Indeed, the answers here aren't correct.

Comment: @DanielFischer if the function would be defined such that $\sin x >0, \forall x$ then will the expression have a limit?

Comment: Well, $\sin$ is what it is. If you replace $\sin$ with a strictly positive function $f$, then the limit may or may not exist. If $f$ is bounded away from $0$ and bounded above, i.e. there are $c,C\in (0,+\infty)$ such that $c \leqslant f(x) \leqslant C$, then the limit exists and is $1$. [The limit exists and is $1$ under much weaker conditions already, but some conditions that prevent $f$ coming "too close" to $0$ or to $+\infty$ are necessary.]

Comment: @DanielFischer This $\frac{1}{a_k^{1/a_k^2}} \to 1$ has $"\infty ^ 0"$ is it $1$ because it's like $x^{-\frac 1 x}$?

Comment: It's even closer to $1$ than that. You know that $x^{-1/x}\to 1$ for $x\to\infty$. Raising that to a power close to $0$, you get that $\Bigl(x^{-1/x}\Bigr)^{1/x}$ converges to $1$ faster. If $x^{-1/x} = 1 - \varepsilon(x)$, then $x^{-1/x^2} \approx 1 - \frac{\varepsilon(x)}{x}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer about the $(2k+1)\pi$ in the numerator we get a limit: $0^0$ and this is undefined...

Comment: No, you look at the point $x_k = (2k+1)\pi$ [you could more generally look at $z_m = m\pi$, I just wanted to avoid going into $\mathbb{C}$]. Then since $\sin x_k = 0$, you get $\left(\frac{0}{x_k}\right)^{1/x_k^2} = 0^{e_k}$, where the exponent is positive, and the base is really $0$. Thus you don't have an indeterminate form there, it's a honest $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer yep that convinced me. Thanks for explanations, you could make this an answer if you want and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit of $f(x) = \bigl(\frac{\sin x}{x}\bigr)^{1/x^2}$ as $x \to \infty$ does not exist. On the one hand, at the zeros of $\sin$ we have zeros of $f$ - at $x_k = k\pi,\; k\in \mathbb{Z}$, the expression becomes $0^{1/(k\pi)^2}$, and $\frac{1}{(k\pi)^2} > 0$ - so

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} f(x_k) = 0,$$

and on the other hand for $a_k = (2k+\frac{1}{2})\pi,\; k\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have

$$f(a_k) = \biggl(\frac{\sin a_k}{a_k}\biggr)^{1/a_k^2} = a_k^{-1/a_k^2},$$

which gives us

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} f(a_k) = 1.$$

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{\sin x}x\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. Because of the sine function the results are highly oscillating.